# Java .contains first instance

Tags: java

I have a string, say

```
"the dog jumped over the fox"
```

If I do `string.contains("the")` it will return `true`.  Is there a way I can pull out just the first instance of `"the"`?

Edit: I realized that my question was ambiguous.  As most of you might have guessed by now, I would like to find the first instance of it, "pull" it out, and replace it with "".

Comment: What do you mean by 'pull out'? Replace with an empty string?

Comment: Or get the First word separated by a space?

Comment: How is the first instance of "the" different from any other instance of "the"?

Comment: `String firstThe = "the";` (For all practical intents and purposes the same as getting it out of the string.)

Comment: It's always hard to pull out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "pull out" you mean remove, you can use `String#replaceFirst`.

i.e.

```
String sentence = "the dog jumped over the fox";
if (sentence.contains("the")) {
    sentence = sentence.replaceFirst("the\\s*","");
}
```

Comment: this is a crappy solution - it would leave double spaces. ie `"foo the bar"` would become `"foo(space)(space)bar"` (two adjacent spaces)

Comment: Could easily get `sentence.trim().replace("  +", " ")` to eliminate the extra spaces...

Comment: Added regex as the pattern to replace.

Comment: I don't think you should use `\s*` - that can will delete `"the"` when it's not its own word. (Maybe this what the OP actually means, I may be wrong, the question is somewhat ambiguous.)

Comment: @Bohemian Since the example was an obviously contrived example, and the OP didn't actually mention words, I don't think the answer necessarily needs to either. It could be put in as an aside, but including it as part of the main answer could actually be harmful.

Comment: @A.R.S. - `the\s*` will match the word "the" optionally followed by a space. If a space doesn't exist, it will still replace it.

Answer (score 0):

you want to *find* the first instance of the string? see `string.indexof`

you wan to *replace* the first instance? see `string.ReplaceFirst`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html